# angular directive is not loading template, static app ( no server )

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am teaching myself Angular and am making a little static app with localStorage. I have hit a snag when though when trying to get a template to load through a directive. I am still pretty new to this, and would appreciate any feedback.  I am spent some time looking through answers to previous questions but none which have addressed my issue.

I am not getting any errors and when I check in dev tools the file is not loading at all.  I have tried different template: and templateUrl configurations and none have worked.

Here is my directive code:

```
angular.module('dropForm', [])
 .directive('dropForm', function(){

  return{
    restrict:'E',
    replace:true,
    templateUrl:'drop-form.html',

    link: function(scope, elem, attr){
    var dropButton = angular.element(document.querySelector('#dropButton'));
    }
  }
});
```

My file structure is basic, this is just a static app. I have a index.html and in that same directory is drop-form.html.  My js files and linked in via script tags in the index.html

Here is my where I call the directive in index.html:

```
<body ng-controller = "mainController">
    <div drop-form> </div>
      <div class = "container main">
        <h1 ng-bind="$storage.toDos.length || 'All Done!'"></h1>
        <div ng-repeat = "todo in $storage.toDos">
          <div style = "" class = "todo-item">
            <div>
              <h5 ng-bind = "todo.text"></h5>
            </div>
            <i class="fa fa-trash" ng-click="destroyTodo(todo)"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The directive template is not loading at all, but I have no erros, please help me understand what i misunderstand here.
Thank you!!

Comment: You have missed `ng-app` directive.

Comment: Did you load your module in main app?

Comment: Your templateUrl should be full url to the html page you are referring. Try to define something like below. templateUrl: 'http://localhost' + 'drop-form.html'. Also try to add appropriate folders to the path based on your project structure.

Answer (score 1):

First you have missed your `ng-app` with name in your case dropForm(in my example I set it to 'myApp') and add it to your body element

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller = "mainController">
    <div drop-form> </div>
      <div class = "container main">
        <h1 ng-bind="$storage.toDos.length || 'All Done!'"></h1>
        <div ng-repeat = "todo in $storage.toDos">
          <div style = "" class = "todo-item">
            <div>
              <h5 ng-bind = "todo.text"></h5>
            </div>
            <i class="fa fa-trash" ng-click="destroyTodo(todo)"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Second.In your directive you have used restriction **'E'**.It means that you must use it only **as Element**: `<drop-form></drop-form>`(**'E'** stand for Element), but you have used as attr.If you want to work with `<div drop-form> </div>`, you must add also restriction **'A'**, `restrict:**'AE'**` or remake `<div drop-form> </div>` to `<drop-form></drop-form>`

and this will be your code

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
 .directive('dropForm', function(){

  return{
    restrict:'AE',
    replace:true,
    templateUrl:'drop-form.html',

    link: function(scope, elem, attr){
    var dropButton = angular.element(document.querySelector('#dropButton'));
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!   My bad.  I was so sure the problem had something to do with the templateUrl,  I totally overlooked the restrict value.   Thank you for pointing that out.  Thank you, lesson learned.

Answer (score 1):

Template won't be loaded from URL unless you **run the app in a server**.